# Which ten States did Trump want to contest?

Tags: united-states, presidential-election, contested-election

[Giuliani's voicemail message](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2EoLug0n0KM) intended for Senator Tommy Tuberville mentions that Trump wanted to contest ten States, which is a lot more than the States the court cases were about. Which States is Giuliani referring to?

Comment: Some states might have been [counted twice](https://www.independent.co.uk/news/world/americas/us-election-2020/trump-election-fraud-lawsuit-michigan-minnesota-b1759424.html).

Answer (score 4):

There do not appear to be ten states. Most articles only referenced six states that were potentially going to be contested. From [AP News](https://apnews.com/article/election-2020-joe-biden-donald-trump-senate-elections-georgia-955739443d5ee6e061878ce0b781b78e):

> some of his Republican allies in Congress plan to formally object to the results, focusing on six battleground states — Arizona, Georgia, Michigan, Nevada, Pennsylvania and Wisconsin

Even in [Trump's speech](https://www.rev.com/blog/transcripts/donald-trump-speech-save-america-rally-transcript-january-6) right before the certification of the results, he only referenced those 6 states listed above.

It appears that the main purpose of Giuliani's call was, in his words, to "slow [the certification] down ... ideally until the end of tomorrow". **Hence, the reference to "10 states" could possibly be off the cuff.**

This was also noted by columnist Seth Abramson on Twitter.

- [tweet regarding Trump's speech](https://twitter.com/SethAbramson/status/1347985031705333760)

  > Note that Trump never comes close to the "ten states" that Rudy Giuliani will shortly plead with Sen. Tommy Tuberville to contest.
- [tweet regarding Giuliani's call](https://twitter.com/SethAbramson/status/1347956981479448579)

  > ... Trump's lawyer Rudy Giuliani calls Sen. Tommy Tuberville to get him to contest *ten* states—including states Trump has never talked about ...

Comment: There have been wacko maps that show Trump as having won California (what?), so maybe that was one of the ten.